# ajustar tamaño del div al tamaño de la tabla que contiene

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap

tengo una tabla dentro de un div. Y queria que dicho div se ampliase hasta ocupar el tamaño total de la tabla que este contiene. Tal y como esta ahora la tabla desborda el div. Si la tabla ocupa poco no tiene problemas, el problema es cuando la tabla es muy grande, ya que la tabla desborda el div y se extiende mas alla de donde deberia.
Este es el codigo: (hace algunas consultas a una base de datos, pero lo importante es la tabla y el div). Hay mas codigo puesto que uso una plantilla para el header pero es tanto codigo que no puedo ponerlo en el post, pero lo esencial esta puesto, ya lo he editado e incluido el css.

```
<div class="cuerpo">
    <div class="container h-100">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
                <form action="listadoProductos.php" method="post">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Id" name="id" value="">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Referencia" name="referencia" value="">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre" name="nombre" value="">
                    <input type="submit" name="filtrar" value="Filtrar">
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center" style="overflow-x:auto;">
                <table border="1">
                    <th>Id</th><th>Nombre</th><th>Precio</th><th>Unidades</th><th>Categoria</th><th>Color</th><th>Talla</th><th>Referencia</th><th>Tipo</th>
                <?php
                require("conexion.php");
                if(!isset($_POST["id"]) or $_POST["id"]=="")
                {   
                    $condicionId="%";
                }
                else
                {
                    $condicionId=$_POST["id"];
                }
                if(!isset($_POST["referencia"]) or $_POST["referencia"]=="")
                {   
                    $condicionReferencia="%";
                }
                else
                {
                    $condicionReferencia=$_POST["referencia"];
                }
                if(!isset($_POST["nombre"]) or $_POST["nombre"]=="")
                {   
                    $condicionNombre="%";
                }
                else
                {
                    $condicionNombre=strtolower($_POST["nombre"])."%";
                }
                
                //$datos=mysqli_query($db,"select * from productos where id like '$condicionId' and referencia like '$condicionReferencia'");
                $sentencia = $db->prepare("select * from productos where id like ? and referencia like ? and lower(nombre) like ?");
                $sentencia->bind_param("sss",$condicionId,$condicionReferencia,$condicionNombre);
                $sentencia->execute();        
                $datos = $sentencia->get_result();
                foreach($datos as $producto)
                {
                    echo("<tr>");
                    echo("<td>".$producto["id"]."</td>");
                    echo("<td>".$producto["nombre"]."</td>");
                    echo("<td>".$producto["precio"]."</td>");
                    echo("<td>".$producto["unidades"]."</td>");
                    echo("<td>".$producto["categoria"]."</td>");
                    echo("<td>".$producto["color"]."</td>");
                    echo("<td>".$producto["talla"]."</td>");
                    echo("<td>".$producto["referencia"]."</td>");
                    echo("<td>".$producto["tipo"]."</td>");
                    echo("<td>".$producto["tipoIva"]."</td>");
                    echo("</tr>");
                }
                ?>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

este es el css:

```
.bannerSuperior
{
    background-color: black;
    /*min-height: 550px;*/
}
.cuerpo
{
    background-color: #ebdef0;
    min-height: 550px;
}
.recuadro
{
    background-color:white;
}

.cuadrosCantidad
{
    min-height:496px;
   
   
}
.cuadrosAddToCart
{
    min-height:472px;
}

.colorTalla
{
    width:100%;
}
.buscar
{
    background-color: lightblue;
    width:100%;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

.panelBuscar
{
    background-color:white;
}

.cuadroLogin
{
    min-height:550px;
}

.cuadroPedidos
{
    min-height: 550px;
}

.textoPedidosPendientes
{
   color: white;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 576px) {
    .text-color {
        color: black !important;
    }
}

.tablaHistorialPedidos
{
    text-align: center;
}

td {
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.botonLink {
text-decoration:none;
font-weight: 600;
font-size: 20px;
/*color:#333333;*/
padding-top:15px;
padding-bottom:15px;
padding-left:40px;
padding-right:40px;
background-color:#FFD27D;
border-color: #d8d8d8;
border-width: 3px;
border-style: solid;
border-radius:35px;
}
```

Comment: Hay datos que se te escapan. ¿Podrías incluir el código css?

Comment: estas usando `bootstrap` lo haz incluido en las cabeceras?

Comment: si he incluido bootstrap en las cabeceras, y yo creo que el fallo esta en el css en el apartado body, en el min-height:550px, ya que es a partir de los 550px cuando me desborda la tabla.

Comment: Si lo importante es la tabla, un ejemplo del html generado con datos nos ayuda a ver el desbordamiento.

Answer (score 2):

Para determinar el ancho y altura de la tabla debes usar `css`. He escrito este script que agrupa todas las variables con una tabla y he incorporado un div general principal donde podrás determinar el ancho y altura.

Te recomiendo usar sólo un echo y insertar los valores en variables. Fíjate en los comentarios que te he escrito junto el código.

A parte, si tienes problemas con el ancho en diferentes pantallas, (tienes problemas con el `responsive` de tu tabla), te recomiendo utilizar los `media queries`.

Aquí un ejemplo:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  principal {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}
```

```css
//CSS

.principal{
width: 95%;
margin:20px; 
height:auto; 
}
.sub{
color: blue;
}
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

td {
border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
  }
```

```html
//CÓDIGO DE PHP CON EL ECHO DE LOS DATOS


// Aquí pasamos los datos a variables  
   // Utilizo el foreach cómo tú  
            
  foreach ($datos as $prdt) { 
    $id=$prdt['id'];
    $nombre=$prdt['nombre'];
    $precio=$prdt['precio'];
    $unidades=$prdt['unidades'];
    $categoria=$prdt['categoria'];
    $color=$prdt['color'];
    $title=$prdt['talla'];
    $referencia=$prdt['referencia'];
    $title=$prdt['tipo'];
    $title=$prdt['tipoIva'];
                  
    // Un solo echo, insertamos todas las variables 
            
   echo '
   
   <!--Este es el div principal, el que tu puedes cambiar de tamaño -->
    <div class="principal"> 
   
    <table>
    <tr>
  <td> <div class="sub"> <p>'.$id.'</p> </div> </td>
  <td> <div class="sub"> <p>'.$nombre.'</p> </div> </td>
  <td> <div class="sub"> <p>'.$precio.'</p> </div> </td>
  <td> <div class="sub"> <p>'.$unidades.'</p> </div> </td>
  <td> <div class="sub"> <p>'.$categoria.'</p> </div> </td>
  <td> <div class="sub"> <p>'.$color.'</p> </div> </td>
  <td> <div class="sub"> <p>'.$talla.'</p> </div> </td>
  <td> <div class="sub"> <p>'.$referencia.'</p> </div> </td>
  <td> <div class="sub"> <p>'.$tipo.'</p> </div> </td>
  <td> <div class="sub"> <p>'.$tipoIva.'</p> </div> </td>
     </tr>
    </table>   
    </div>
    ';
    }
```

Links de referencia (Te recomiendo echarle un ojo):

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13027386/how-to-echo-variable-in-a-div-using-php

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31929621/echo-multiple-variables-in-same-line-bash

Comment: @guillanBesada ¿Es esto lo que buscabas?